# Navigation with bottom

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVVM7.jpg)I use bottom navigation in my application, but I do not know how to switch from one fragment bottom to a new fragment at the click of a button in this case

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.plantoplans);

        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        replaceFragment(new ProfilFragment());

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.profil:

                    replaceFragment(new ProfilFragment());

                    break;

                case R.id.lessons:

                    replaceFragment(new LessonsFragment());

                    break;

                case R.id.plan:

                    replaceFragment(new PlanFragment());

                    break;

            }

            return true;

        });

    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

I tried to use the usual transition between fragments, the transition from activity to fragment

Comment: Hi there, did you try at least